# Point compass to one direction

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have a `UIImageView` representing a simple knob: it has nothing to do with stereo hi-fi, it represents a sort of compass:

[image]

My goal is the following: I want the compass to point a precise direction, starting from the current position of the device (and it must update too: if the user turns the device elsewhere, the knob should rotate accordingly).

What I tried until now:

I have this function:

```
func getRadiansBearing()->Double{

        // body of degreesToRadians: return degrees * M_PI / 180.0

        // data[1]._lat and _lon contains my current position
        let lat1 = degreesToRadians(data[1]._lat)
        let lon1 = degreesToRadians(data[1]._lon)

        // data[0]._lat and _lon contains the target position
        let lat2 = degreesToRadians(data[0]._lat)
        let lon2 = degreesToRadians(data[0]._lon)

        let dLon = lon2 - lon1;

        let y = sin(dLon)*cos(lat2)
        let x = cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dLon)

        var radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

        if(radiansBearing < 0.0)
        {
            radiansBearing = radiansBearing+2*M_PI
        }

        return radiansBearing

    }
```

and I call it this way, using the `CoreLocation` framework:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return;
        }

        // data is an array of structs
        data[1]._lat = location.coordinate.latitude
        data[1]._lon = location.coordinate.longitude

        geoAngle = getRadiansBearing()

    }
```

and:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {

        let direction = -newHeading.trueHeading
        let dir2 = degreesToRadians(direction)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
            self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(dir2) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180) + CGFloat(self.geoAngle))
        })

    }
```

Problem is, for some reason the knob turns once into one (wrong) direction, then stops working.

Can you help me? Any tip is appreciated!   :-)

P.S.: I red many related posts, none solves this issue

Comment: I'd take out the animation first and see if it works, if not then put some print statements in the didUpdateHeading and make sure thats called, and check the value of geoAngle to see if its being updated. See if that gets you anywhere

Comment: @daven11: it's exactly what I did before posting   :-)  They get updated, maybe the problem is in the animation

Comment: sorry to state the obvious - difficult to tell how experienced developers are on here. I haven't used the CoreLocation framework so good luck

Answer (score 0):

> Consider latitude as x, and longitude as y for now.

**Pre-requisites:**

1. Destination location must be known.
2. Current location must be known.

I would show you how to calculate the angle towards the direction now. It is as follows!

> 1. Get the current location and destination location's latitude and longitude.

**Pseudo Code:**

Let, currentLocation = ( lat, long )
Let, destinationLocation = ( lat, long )
angleTowardsDestination = ?

> 2. Calculate the base and hypotenuse for Pythagorus theorem.

Now,
 base = √((currentLocation.lat - destinationLocation.lat)<sup>2</sup> - (currentLocation.long - currentLocation.long)<sup>2</sup>) 
hypotenuse = √((currentLocation.lat - destinationLocation.lat)<sup>2</sup> - (currentLocation.long - destinationLocation.long)<sup>2</sup>)

> 3. Calculate the angle now!

angleTowardsDestination = Cos<sup>-1</sup>( base / hypotenuse )

And, that's the angle you need in degrees. Feel free to convert it to radian if needed.

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari

Comment: maybe I found what's wrong in the code: in the last function body, direction must be cast to CGFloat and there's no need to convert it to radians. Thanks anyway for your comment  :-)

Comment: Your Welcome. And, good luck with your project. Do write an update on what worked for you! It can help someone in the future.